# Displaying images successively (like a smooth video) with the single click of button in GUI python

Tags: image, user-interface, video

I am working on a project where I have a folder where all the required images are being stored I want a GUI in python which will have a button and display screen. As I click the button I want to display all the images from the same folder one after other in the same screen like a smooth video (just by one click). 
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Are they all the same size? Is the order important? What OS?

Comment: Yes all are having same size... Yes order is important... want to work on windows and linux both